# Reformat code in IntelliJ IDEA (macOS) does not work

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Use IntelliJ IDEA for macOS. Problem

1. Whenever I do <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (shortcut to reformat code in macOS), code clean up does not apply.

- I noticed that because I turned on the Final Modifier already (Make generated local variables final and Make generated parameters final in *Settings*: *Editor* -> *Code Style* -> *Java* -> *Code Generation*). But after shortcut, no finals are added.
- However, if I do <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open the reformat dialog and click run, it does add final to variables and parameters). It also work when I right click the file and choose reformat code.
- I don't know why, isn't <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> a shortcut that should do exactly the same thing?

2. This bring out my other question, is <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd> really applying all my customize settings in Code Style and Inspections (assume I selected the right scheme (under Code Style) and profile (under inspections)?
3. My last question is, for example, let's say I have a custom scheme in IDE level for Code Style. Every time when I clone a project from let's say GitHub, how do I make the project automatically using my custom scheme instead of using the Project scheme and the Default scheme? Every time I have to go to Code Style and manually switch from "Stored in Project" to "Stored in IDE", so that I can select my custom scheme and click apply. Is there an easy way? Same for Inspections profile, I have to manually switch.

I have tried to solve these for so long, any help will be appreciated! Below are some links I found, but didn't solve my questions

1. [Reformat code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html?keymap=secondary_macos)
2. [Reformat file dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-file-dialog.html?keymap=secondary_macos)
3. [Code Style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-code-style.html?keymap=secondary_macos)

Comment: 1. Code cleanup and code formatting are two different features. If you would like to apply them simultaneously, use save shortcut and enable both features in "Actions on save": https://i.imgur.com/QBQNa2r.png

Comment: 1. The "Code generation" tab (make generated local variables final setting) affects only code generation (e.g. Cmd+N inside class), but not code formatting.

Comment: 3. You can configure a scheme for all new projects under "File | New project setup| Preferences for new projects": https://i.imgur.com/mOyUNOX.png

Answer (score 0):

MacOS shortcut for code cleanup, try
`^` + `⌥`+ `⌘` +`L`